# using Facebook iOS SDK 2, how do I like a page? - "Application must be on whitelist"

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, oauth

How do I "like" a page using the new Facebook iOS SDK? (http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

I'm currently attempting to do it with:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[_facebook accessToken],@"access_token",nil];
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"cocacola/likes" andParams:dict andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

This doesn't work. When I `NSLog([error description]);` I get:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x6a50160 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x6a4fd40 [0x250b380]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x6a4fc80 [0x250b380]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x6a50000 [0x250b380]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x6a500e0 [0x250b380]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x6a50080 [0x250b380]>{contents = "(#3) Application must be on whitelist"}
}
}
```

I have added my IP (the IP address my computer, as I'm running from the simulator, gets when visiting www.whatismyip.com ) to the whitelist in my Facebook application's white list under advanced settings.

Thanks!
Tristan

Comment: Facebook does not allow liking of pages or any other objects on user's behalf. The only exception is that you can like user posts. Facebook is looking into allowing to like pages, but they didn't make any commitments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's a well known, but unconfirmed, bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10714.

It may help if you voted for the bug in Facebook's bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Partial solutions have been suggested, though the user experience is only great if the user is already logged in to FB -- this may be likely for many but not all users, so it remains an imperfect approach.

http://angelolloqui.blogspot.com/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html

Answer (score 2):

1)Use the facebook iOS SDk to check if the user is logged in. 
2)Once the user is logged in, load the facebook Like API into a webview. 
See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#
You should load something like this (format with appropiate params where you see %@, %i):
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=%@&layout=%@&show_faces=%@&width=%i&action=%@&colorscheme=%@&font=%@"

3)Profit.

Also, the reason the user won't have to login is because a cookie will be saved once they log in using the Facebook iOS SDK login screen (If you are doing it in your app and not Safari/FB app).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it's broken by design. Using Facebook API you are only allowed to liking posts (by sending post request to https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes&auth_token=...), nothing else. Right now there is only one application which is allowed to liking pages using facebook api, it's "causes".