# iPhone facebook integration

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am using Graph API in my application. I am fetching user's facebook wall feeds using graph API also getting details of particular post i.e (Like count,Comments etc).
but i want to allow user to Like and Comment any post from the application itself.
what is the request format for that?

Please help me or give any pointers.

Regards,
Sanket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for LIKE option
We should use following method for like option.

```
-(void) requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath 
               andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params 
           andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod 
             andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate
```

graphPath = /OBJECT_ID/likes
Paramas = dictionary with comment ,for like option use empty dictionary
HttpMethod should be POST

you should get response = true if the LIKE request is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You would be well served to check out the [Publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) section of the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/). It provides information such as this.

One example is liking, which is defined as:

> Method: /OBJECT_ID/likes
>
> Description:     Like the given object (if it has a /likes connection)
>
> Arguments:  none

Basically, just initiate a Graph API call to something like:

```
[facebookObject requestWithGraphPath:@"98423808305/likes" andDelegate:self];
```

That will "like" a picture from Coca-Cola (ID taken from the documentation).

---

**Edit 1**

According to the documentation:

> Most write operations require [extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) for the active user. See the [authentication guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for details on how you can request extended permissions from the user during the authentication step.

Are you sure you have enough privileges? Unfortunately the documentation is very unclear as to whether it serves the dual purpose of liking the object and returning the likes already on that object.

---

**Edit 2**

I did some more research into what could be causing this and came across [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809652/using-facebook-ios-sdk-2-how-do-i-like-a-page-application-must-be-on-whiteli) that indicated that the code I posted above using `requestWithGraphPath::` should work. However, it does not due to a [bug on Facebook's Bug Tracker](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10714).

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no way to "like" an object via the Graph API, which seems very strange to me. Perhaps it is possible with the legacy REST API instead of the Graph API?

---

**Edit 3**

Well, it looks like your best bet is the `stream.addLike` method of the [legacy REST API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) which you can still call using the Facebook iOS SDK. You should be able to use the [`stream.addLike`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.addLike/) method to "like" something in the "stream". Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to support photos, videos, etc. Only posts and comments.

Comment: I have tried with method but it returns list of Persons who have liked that object.
It doesn't mark that object "LIKE".

Comment: actually the method you are suggesting is ideal one to mark Like from iphone app. but i didnt get any success with it. i have also tried with extended permission. 
The documentation is not very clear about this  Like feature.

Comment: @user130934 I did some more research and have edited my answer again. Once I am at home (and not behind the company firewall) I will look into the legacy REST API and see if I can figure out a way to get this to work. I am currently working with the FB iOS SDK as well and would have to say I am invested in figuring this out with you.